# preg_replace content return

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

my data in mysql contains (in row):

```
text text text text
<img border="0" src="http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/3397/image22232822360.jpg" /><br />
<br />
OMG BIG TEXT<br />
<br />
text text text etc.
```

It's possbile remove **any/everyting** content and only leave:

```
<img border="0" src="http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/3397/image22232822360.jpg" />
```

If yes, how should it look like ?

Comment: you can take the string from http:// .jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match('/<img([^>]*)>/i',$string, $match);
```

$match[0] will have your value;